# Access browser certificate store using javascript

Tags: javascript, cryptography, ejbca

how can i access browser certificate store, using javascript ,to know if a CA's Root certificate exists or not ?

Comment: You cannot do that with JavaScript. The solution is to use a well known CA.

Comment: pardon me please , i couldn't get your reply . i need to check the browser store for a particulat CA's Root using javascript.It doesn't fulfil my requirements .

Comment: You cannot do that using JavaScript.  If you explain your reasoning for needing you may get alternative suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't find such JavaScript library that does the above mentioned task.so its not possible using JavaScript but you can do the same with an Applet in java.